# anacondaでインストールしたIDLEがモジュールを認識しない

Tags: python, python3, anaconda

anacondaでpython3.6をインストールしました。しかし、今までのPCで使っていたIDLEがモジュールを読み込みません。具体的には、例えばnumpyをインポートしようとすると、

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

と、エラーを吐きます。spyderでは正常に動作するので、モジュール自体はインストールされていると思います。PCはWindows 10、64bitでインストールしました。前のPCではWindows 8.1でpython3.5を使っていました。どなたか原因のわかる方いらっしゃいますか。また、他にお勧めの開発環境などあると教えていただけると幸いです。

追記：
pycharmをインストールしてみましたが、こちらでもモジュールを読み込めませんでした。

```
import sys
print(sys.version)
```

と入力したところ、spyder, idle, pycharm 全てで

```
3.6.4 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Jan 16 2018, 10:22:32) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)]
```

と出力されました。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/117756

Comment: ググってみたらマルチポストはマナー違反なんですね。ご指摘ありがとうございます。以後気を付けます。